# How can I check that cleaned_data['field'] is set and has a value, where 0 is valid, with a Django ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, validation

If `field1` and `field2` don't exist, or do exist but are empty, `fieldX` should show a validation error. However, `field1` and `field2` are a `FloatFields` that can be `0`, and so this should evaluate to True. Something like:

```
def clean_fieldX(self):
    if self.cleaned_data.get('field1') is None or self.cleaned_data.get('field2') is None:
        raise forms.ValidationError('fieldX was not set properly')
```

This doesn't work - it raises the validation error regardless.

For context, `field1` and `field2` are hidden, set by js depending on user actions, and the visible `fieldX` provides visual feedback

Comment: Why validationError should be raised if field1 and field2 are not Empty?

Comment: So, what is your question? That would work, although it should be in the generic `clean()` method.

Comment: It doesn't work (it passes the `if` and raises the `validation error`, even with the values set at non-zero. I didn't put it in `clean()` because the validation error should be attached to `fieldX`, unless there's a smarter way to do so?

Comment: There is: [`add_error()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error).

Comment: how about using `min_value=0.0` and `required=True` form field attributes?

Comment: If I set `required=True` on `field1` and `field2`, they would still need to raise a different validation error, attached to `fieldX`, rather than on themselves, when the fields are empty

Answer (score 0):

I think this didn't work because the fields weren't ready to be called in `cleaned_data`, whereas all `clean_field` methods are already called when running `clean()`. I may be wrong, but this worked as expected and attached the message to `fieldX`:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.cleaned_data.get('field1') is None or self.cleaned_data.get('field2') is None:
        raise ValidationError({'fieldX ': ValidationError(_('fieldX was not set properly!'), code='required')})
```

Comment: Yes, if you're [validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), use `clean`, not `clean_field`.

Comment: Oops, forgot to change it, fixed